# turn single header in pandas dataframe to multiple headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have the following dataframe with headers and data

```
   T  |  A - x | A - y | B - x | B - y |
1  m  |    a   |   b   |    c  |   d   |
2  n  |    a   |   b   |    c  |   d   |
```

where `1` and `2` are just index

How can I convert it to the two following formats?

```
   T  |  A     |   A   |    B  |   B   |
      |  x     |   y   |    x  |   y   |
1  m  |    a   |   b   |    c  |   d   |
2  n  |    a   |   b   |    c  |   d   |
```

```
   T  |  A     |       |    B  |       |
      |  x     |   y   |    x  |   y   |
1  m  |    a   |   b   |    c  |   d   |
2  n  |    a   |   b   |    c  |   d   |
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `MultiIndex` for columns with separator, first convert all non separator column(s) to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then use `split`:

```
df = df.set_index('T')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(' - ', expand=True)
print (df)
   A     B   
   x  y  x  y
T            
m  a  b  c  d
n  a  b  c  d
```

If use only:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(' - ', expand=True)
print (df)
    T  A     B   
  NaN  x  y  x  y
0   m  a  b  c  d
1   n  a  b  c  d
```

get `NaN` for first level for `T`.

If need it is possible replace it by empty string:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(' - ', expand=True)

f = lambda x: '' if pd.isna(x) else x
df = df.rename(columns=f)
print (df)
   T  A     B   
      x  y  x  y
0  m  a  b  c  d
1  n  a  b  c  d
```

---

If need display all levels in `MultiIndex` check [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#available-options):

> *display.multi_sparse*
> **True**
> “Sparsify” MultiIndex display (don’t display repeated elements in outer levels within groups)

```
#if need temporary use option
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df)
   A  A  B  B
   x  y  x  y
T            
m  a  b  c  d
n  a  b  c  d
```